# Unable to install typings for Google APIs via ambient DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to install TypeScript `.d.ts` typings for Google API from [DefinitelyTyped/google-apps-script](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/google-apps-script). I know it's available among ambient packages:

```
$ typings search --ambient google

Showing 20 of 39 results...

NAME                                                      SOURCE HOMEPAGE                                              DESCRIPTION UPDATED                  VERSIONS
angular-google-analytics                                  dt     https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics             2015-11-19T15:50:48.000Z 2       
angular-google-analytics/angular-google-analytics-service dt     https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics             2016-02-15T16:20:30.000Z 3       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.base                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.cache               dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.calendar            dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.charts              dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.contacts            dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.content             dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.document            dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.drive               dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.forms               dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.gmail               dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.groups              dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.html                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.jdbc                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.language            dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.lock                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.mail                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps                dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2       
google-apps-script/google-apps-script.optimization        dt     https://developers.google.com/apps-script/                        2015-11-12T02:10:55.000Z 2
```

but I'm not able to install any of them with:

```
$ typings i --ambient "google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps"
```

It throws an error:

```
? Found google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps typings for DefinitelyTyped. Continue? Yes
Installing google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps@~0.0.0 (DefinitelyTyped)...

typings ERR! message ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/project/path/typings/main/ambient/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps.d.ts'

typings ERR! cwd /project/path
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.3.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typings/dist/bin/typings-install.js" "--ambient" "google-apps-script/google-apps-script.maps"
typings ERR! node -v v4.2.2
typings ERR! typings -v 0.6.8
typings ERR! code ENOENT

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

It's obviously able to find the package but it seems like it gets confused because name of the package contains `/` so it tries to access wrong directory.

Could this be an issue with `typings` tool?

Comment: I copied your example and it worked for me. I am using typings version 0.7.9 on Windows 7.

Comment: I updated to the latest `typings@0.7.9` and you're right, it works now. I assume this issue has been resolved in one of the recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I just had to update to the latest version of `typings` where this issue has been resolved.

Comment: thanks for that, was scratching my head fo an hour. using v 7.12 it woudlnt install the typings unless I removed the typing folder and run typings install